# Google Spreadsheet Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working in a google document spreadsheet to make a list of active customers. I am attempting to create a script that when a completion date is entered, that row (all the customer info) is transfered to another sheet and/or deleted. I started a script but it isn't working properly.

```
function myFunction() {
'var ssdate = spreadsheet.column B'
// the "if" clause : if (date = 1) {
// the "then" clause : then ( move row to sheet 2)
}
```

Since this is my first time, I am sure this needs some work, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to read the Google Apps Script [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles.html) and [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide) first. They will give you a much better quick start.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following example:

```
var ddate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM-dd-yy");

function checkDate(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var rowsNumber = rows.getNumRows();
  var column = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = column.getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i <= rowsNumber -1; i++){

    var customerData = values[i];
    var customerDate = customerData[2];
    var myRow = Math.round(i) +1;
    var conCustomerDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(customerDate), "GMT", "MM-dd-yy");

    if (conCustomerDate > ddate){

      sheet.getRange("D" + myRow).setValue("OK");

    } 

    else {

      sheet.getRange("D" + myRow).setValue("Old");

    }

  }

}
```